# tinymce - how to set the focus to the first editor on a page with multiple editors?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

if I have more than one tinymce editor on a page, every action I do goes to the last editor unless I explicitly click on the editor I want to edit.  For example, I made a plugin, which displays a dialog box, I type something in the dialog box and it should go to the first editor (I launch the dialog box from the first editor) but it goes to the last one, as it is the currently active editor.

How do I make the first editor active, once the page is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand("mce_editor_0", "mceFocus");
```

taken from [here](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=4340)

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple tinyMCE forms on one page, I recommend
Command: runScript
Target: tinyMCE.get('textarea_id').setContent('Your Text')